# How to set a shared example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm just learning to write specs in ruby, and rails. So I do have two similar models that act similar when voted: question and answer. So I try to not duplicate code and write shared example for this two.

```
RSpec.shared_examples_for 'User Votable' do

  let!(:user){ create :user } 
  let!(:sample_user){ create :user }   
  let!(:vote){ create :vote, user: user, votable: votable, vote_field: 1}   

  it 'user different from resource user is accapteble' do        
    expect(votable.user_voted?(sample_user)).to be_falsy
  end   

  it 'user similar to resource user is accapteble' do

    expect(votable.user_voted?(user)).to be_truthy
  end

end
```

And a test itself

```
describe 'user_voted?' do 
  def votable
    subject{ build(:question)}
  end
  it_behaves_like 'User Votable'
end
```

The last it in this spec fails( I think because of subject - it does not change when I create a vote)
So I would be very happy if I could manage and understand how to do it right way. And very thankful for any advice

Also when I try to use mock like this, it complains on not having primary key

```
allow(:question){create :question}

Failures:
```

1) Question user_voted? behaves like User Votable user similar to resource user is accapteble
     Failure/Error: expect(votable.user_voted?(user)).to be_truthy

```
   expected: truthy value
        got: false
 Shared Example Group: "User Votable" called from ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:23
```

Comment: Just do `def votable; build(:question); end`

Comment: def votable  build(:question)  end I do recieve a similar error(updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a `votable` method could you set the `subject` as such:

```
it_behaves_like 'User Votable' do
  subject { build(:question) }
end
```

Comment: And how should I address this subject in my spec?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to use `subject`, you can just set whatever context you want using `let` and it will be available within the block:

```
describe 'user_voted?' do 
  let(:votable) { build(:question) }
  it_behaves_like 'User Votable'
end
```

Then you can just refer to `votable` within your shared example and it will be defined by the context:

```
RSpec.shared_examples_for 'User Votable' do
  let!(:user) { create :user } 
  let!(:sample_user) { create :user }   
  let!(:vote) { create :vote, user: user, votable: votable, vote_field: 1 }

  it 'user different from resource user is acceptable' do        
    expect(votable.user_voted?(sample_user)).to be_falsy
  end   

  it 'user similar to resource user is acceptable' do
    expect(votable.user_voted?(user)).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

You can also incidentally pass parameters into the `it_behaves_like` block for more flexibility.

Ref: [Providing context to a shared group using a block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block)

(Note: fixed some spelling typos above.)